# Branch a version in CVS

Tags: version-control, cvs, trunk

So i have a source tree that i want to clean up in CVS.

What a really want is to branch the old stuff off, but never merge in back in. But so i can have an eclipse workspace to access and make some changes if i need to.

And then we clean up the main trunk (by removing things we dont need anymore) and keep developing. Then when we hit a new release, we branch it off again.

Im not sure how this works in CVS. So if somebody could explain the best way to go about it that would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question? Do you want to know the commandline syntax for creating a branch? Best practices for branching and merging?

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using it any more why not just tagging it as a version an proceed with the clean up in the HEAD.

That is what we do in our development tree. If we need to correct something that applies to an old version we just branch that version at that time, but not before.

Answer (score 2):

With CVS it's a lot easier to tag and deal with branches only when you need to make the changes - that seems to be the best practice. Here's a site I found helpful back before we switched to SVN:

http://owen.sj.ca.us/rkowen/howto/cvs.html#branches